# Re-training keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've got keras model traing and I'm using this model to generate data. I want to use that data to re-traing my model. After training this model seems to know how to predict new data, but somehow lost knowledge about previous data. I do not compile model again before training. There is some special actions to perform re-training in keras?

Comment: save model and re-load before re-training..

Comment: That's what I'm doing. Is this maybe caused because of data proportions? In first training I used 120k training data sets. In re-traing only 5k sets.

Comment: if you are loading the same model as before and then re-training it.. data is not lost.

Comment: I'm going to look for errors then. Thanks :)